# React async function resets state to null after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

The following code will return an error for an unhandled promise rejection `'cannot read property 'lastVisiblePost' of undefined` when you click the pagination button.

It seems that it's setting state to null right after it does the initial `getPosts`.

It works the first run, but the moment you hit the button that calls `getPosts` state will equal `null`.

```js
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        listState: 'top',
        allPosts: [],
        lastVisiblePost: null
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { user } = await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()

        this.getPosts()
    }

    async getPosts() {
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log(this.state.lastVisiblePost)
        let posts = null
        if (this.state.lastVisiblePost) {
            posts = await firebase.firestore()
                    .collection('posts')
                    .orderBy('likes')
                    .startAfter(last)
                    .limit(2)
                    .get()
        } else {
            posts = await firebase.firestore()
                    .collection('posts')
                    .orderBy('likes')
                    .limit(2)
                    .get()
        }
        let newPosts = []
        posts.forEach(post => {
            newPosts.push({
                id: post.id,
                data: post.data()
            })
        })

        console.log(posts.docs)
        console.log("memes", posts.docs[posts.docs.length - 1])

        this.setState({
            allPosts: newPosts,
            lastVisiblePost: posts.docs[posts.docs.length - 1]
        }, () => {
            console.log("doink", this.state)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { listState, allPosts } = this.state

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                { /* Logo */ }
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image style={styles.logo} source={anywayLogo} />
                </View>
                { /* Top and New Buttons */ }
                <View style={styles.topAndNewContainer}>
                    <Text style={[styles.topAndNewText, listState === 'top' ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'black' }]} onPress={() => this.setState({listState: 'top'})}>top</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.topAndNewText, listState === 'new' ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'black' }]} onPress={() => this.setState({listState: 'new'})}>new</Text>
                </View>
                { /* Feed */ }
                <View style={styles.feedContainer}>
                    {
                        allPosts.map(post => {
                            return (<Text key={post.id}>{post.data.title}</Text>)
                        })
                    }
                </View>
                <Button title="Next page" onPress={this.getPosts} />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

Is async await breaking my state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `getPosts` function isn't properly bound to your component, so `this` is referring to the `getPosts` function and not your component. Since it doesn't have any state property, you get the error.

There are two ways to do this, either you bind in your constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listState: 'top',
      allPosts: [],
      lastVisiblePost: null
    }

    this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this)
  }
}
```

Or you use [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) babel plugin, and then you can declare component methods as arrow functions, which do not provide their own `this` and so the `this` keyword will automatically refer to your component:

```
getPosts = async () => {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: You got it - the second one was the issue, I messed up the function declaration syntax - big yikes!

Comment: to be clear either one would have worked, the first or the second, but the second is a nicer syntax imo. Just remember that anytime you need to reference your component via `this` your methods should be properly bound. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state in the constructor otherwise it won't be defined in the rest of your functions.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    listState: 'top',
    allPosts: [],
    lastVisiblePost: null
   }
}
```

Comment: It is set using `state` on line 2

Comment: You need to do it within the constructor function.